# Proving the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

So I'm working through some questions in my book and I don't understand how to finish out the attached problem.  For the first 5 blanks here is what I got:

> Since $f$ is continuous on $[16,25]$ and differentiable on $(16,25)$
>
> $(16,25)$
>
> $\frac{f(19)-f(16)}{19-16}=\frac{\sqrt{19}-4}{3}=f'(c)$
>
> $\frac{1}{8}$
>
> $\frac{1}{10}$

Hints on the next part?  I just don't understand what I'm supposed to put there.

[image: MVT Proof]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the third blank I think they intended you to write the formula $f'(c) = 1/(2\sqrt{c})$, which you should have used when you calculated the bounds for the fourth and fifth blanks. The last two lines are just manipulations of $1/10<f'(c)<1/8$. Multiply this by $3$ for the second-to-last line, and then add $4$ for the last line. Note that the last line ends with "which is what we wanted to show", so it should obviously be a restatement of the conclusion of the proposition.

Comment: The only part of your answer I don't understand is how you got $f'(c)=1/(2\sqrt{c})$

Comment: They say in the problem $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. What is the derivative of this?

Comment: Ahhh.. gotcha.  Thanks for that clarification